# Naming the relation of a competition and its sports

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

I'm trying to find a word for the relation between a competition or an event and its offered sports.

Let's take the Olympic Games for example:

The event would be the Olympic Games. You can participate in different sports like boxing. A specific match would then be associated to a [insert word here] which identifies its event and sport.

In my case I have eSport competitions which offer different video games (here equal to sports) you can participate in.

Combinations are for example:

```
ESL One 2015 - DotA 2
ESL One 2015 - CS:GO
ESL One 2015 - Hearthstone
```

How would you call these combinations?

Comment: How about *tournament*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me, however the different sports of the Olympic Games can be called Olympic disciplines. See OED:

> b. spec. A branch or field of sporting activity; a subcategory or element of a particular sport.

So if you're looking for a synonym of sport in the context of a definite set of sports, this word may be the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> Leg ? [(Collins)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leg)

Particularly the fourth one.

- a section or part of a journey or course
- a single stage, lap, length, etc,
- in a relay race either one of two races on which a cumulative bet has
  been placed
- one of a series of games, matches, or parts of games

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [***event***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/event) which means:

***Each of several particular contests*** making up ***a sports competition***: ‘he repeated the success in the four-lap, 600 cc event’

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is one word to describe both relationships, in what appears to be a relational database entity relationship mapping exercise. As best as I can see, the relations are different.

The event (e.g. Olympics, World Cup committee) will *program* all contests.

A league or sports governing body (e.g. FIFA) will *sponsor* or *govern* the contests.